# What is the best Olympic weightlifting instructional?

Tags: weightlifting, books, olympic

I am moving from strength training to power training in order to improve athletic performance. Specifically, I am adding the clean and jerk (no snatch for now) to my program. I am not looking to compete in Olympic weightlifting. Rather, I am using the Olympic lifts to improve my power output.

I therefore need instruction on the Olympic lifts beyond Rippetoe's (excellent) overview of the power clean in Starting Strength. I train at home, so in addition to in-person coaching, I'd like to have a book or DVD available as reference on the clean, jerk, and perhaps the snatch in the future. Which sources should I look to?

Comment: Per [the powerlifting version of the question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/powerlifting-books), I would be open to making this a community wiki. If we get any answers, that is. :)

Comment: I believe this is something that truly requires a coach.

Comment: I agree, and have been getting such coaching. But a definitive resource is accessible in ways that a coach is not, and is usually cheaper. The purpose of the DVD or book is to supplement rather than supplant.

Answer (score 1):

On t-nation there is a nice video section of exercises that instruct the proper form.

http://www.t-nation.com/strength-training-search/video/exercise-videos

Jim Wendler has a pretty cool program called the 531 for strength programing.

http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/how_to_build_pure_strength

I am in no way affiliated.  Just started the 531 and thought I would see if that fit what you needed.

Worth looking into.

Comment: 5/3/1 isn't designed around the Oly lifts, even though they can complement the program.  Nor does it provide any input on how to perform the Oly lifts as the OP wanted.

Comment: NOTE: I like 5-3-1, and am currently using it.  It just isn't the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: No, however the second portion of my answer was.

Comment: Ah, I think that got lost.  If you edit your answer to put the instructional videos first, and draw more attention to it, this would be a much better answer.  I agree that the Wendler program is great, but it should be an addendum, and not the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a book, but Glenn Pendlay's intro to performing the clean is a good start:

http://californiastrength.com/videos/viewvideo/44/clean/clean-how-to-video-part-one

There's a couple drills to help you get used to the hip movement required for the second pull (the actual clean part):

- [Dirty Dancing](http://www.pendlay.com/Dirty-Dancing_df_71.html)
- [Rock and Roll](http://www.pendlay.com/The-Rock-and-Roll-Drill-_df_70.html)

You may also want to check out other links from this page: http://ironstrong.org/index.php?/topic/11-the-clean/

I don't know of any books, but if you look for instructional videos from Glenn Pendlay and Mike Burgener, you can get what you are looking for.